# "zustimmen" with pronoun

Tags: verb, declension

The verb [zustimmen](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/zustimmen) is used with a dative, whether you're agreeing to a person or to a statement.

(a) What do we do if we want to say "I agree with that"? Would

> Ich stimme das zu

be correct?

(b) What about "I agree that ..."? Would it be

> Ich stimme zu, dass ...

Or should we add some da-compound, like

> Ich stimme damit zu, dass ...

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, *zustimmen* is used with the Dativ case. So, your first example (a) is not correct, because Dativ of *das* is *dem*, not *das*:

> Ich stimme dem zu.

(b) and (c) are fine. You can use *zustimmen* with a *dass* sub-clause ([Inhaltssatz](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Objekt/Inhaltssatz.html))

Comment: I wonder though, why `dem` instead of `der`? Do we just use the masculine pronoun by default?

Comment: `Ich stimme damit zu, dass …` only works, if `damit` refers to something else, like `Ich finde diese Idee toll. Ich stimme damit zu, dass …`.

Comment: Can we say `Ich stimme damit zu, dass wir jetzt zur Post gehen sollen`?

Comment: @Mika H.: It is a neutral pronoun, not masculine. Also, Toscho's remark is a bit confusing; the _damit_ doesn't have anything to do with _zustimmen_, it means _thus_ (and I'd prefer _somit_ instead). However, you can say _Ich stimme dem zu, daß_.